# Typescript for passportjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, typescript, passport.js

I'm very new to typescript. The idea sounds great and so I want to give it a try and port existing javascript code to typescript. The project I want to port uses nodejs/expressjs and mongoose at the backend and for the frontend angularjs with angularui.

Angular, Node/Express, jQuery and many other npm packages can be found at the [DefinitelyTyped repo](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) or [typescript-node-definitions repo](https://github.com/soywiz/typescript-node-definitions)
For Mongoose there are several definition files out there. I need to figure out which one to use.

The only two npm packages I can not find are [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/) and [connect-mongodb](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) (I use it for session storage)

The definitions for connect-mongodb are not very important since I use it only in one place, but the passportjs definitions would be really helpful. Do you know where I can find them? Or are there no definitions for passportjs?

Thanks
Tschoartschi

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Are you planning to rewrite PassportJS as Typescript? Passport is install through npm as - npm install passport

Comment: No I don't want to rewrite passportjs. I just want the type definitions to get intellisense/code completion for passportjs. It would be nicer to have code completion in the IDE instead of always looking up the documentation. It should just ease and speed up coding. Expecially if new team members join, this would be neat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the definitions are not on DT you will have a tough time finding them since that is the place where people share their work.

But to get started you don't need the definitions. If you reference `node.d.ts` in your project the following code will compile just fine:

```
var passport = require('passport')
```

Notice `var passport` instead of `import passport`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Its true what you wrote but it feels a little bit hacky if you just have definitions for half of your npm packages. Something I recognized just now is, that the definition for angularjs is for version 1.0 (the comment in the file says that, see [link](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts) ) but we are using AngularJS 1.2. So hopefully there is no problem...

Comment: @tschoartschi its is actually 1.2, that comment was invalid. I've fixed it now. Thanks for pointing it out.